# eigen library selfadjointView problem

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I am persistently getting error messages whenever I try to use the selfadjointView property of any matrix or sparse matrix using the eigen library. Below is a simple code to check that. In my program I do try with self-adjoint matrix:

```
#define EIGEN_YES_I_KNOW_SPARSE_MODULE_IS_NOT_STABLE_YET
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <iostream>

using namespace Eigen;
int main ()
{
SparseMatrix<float>  mat(3,3);
Matrix<float, 3, 1> vec;
std::cout<<mat.selfadjointView<>()*vec;
}
```

The error message I get is: 
error: no matching function for call to ‚'Eigen::SparseMatrix::selfadjointView()‚

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the template argument, so it should read `mat.selfadjointView<Upper>()` or `mat.selfadjointView<Lower>()` . The first one means that it should use the entries in the upper triangular part of `mat` and fill the lower triangular part to make the matrix self-adjoint. The second one is the other way around.

Comment: Thanks Jitse, that was helpful. I was hoping to gain more speed by using this selfadjointView method, but that did not happen.